# Wordpress keeps going back to old homepage/theme

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I have a strange problem. Some days ago i started making my homepage with the responsive theme.

After a while i was not happy and decided to start all over again with a new theme.

I downloaded the WordPress reset app to get rid of everything i made so far and everything seemed to work out fine.

Installed my new theme (Ravel) and started building my page again. Yesterday i was done but now to my problem...

When i log out from admin view and give the url i come to my new page but as soon as i click on the header for example that takes you back to the "home" page it suddenly takes me back to my old homepage with old theme/menus and everything???

If i then write the url again to my homepage it takes me again to old one and if i click around there sometimes the new theme come back and then next click old page and so on...

What can be the problem here?

Thanks for you help

Comment: Clear the cache and tmp files. Should fix it.

Comment: well it works shortly if if clear the cache and everything else in Explorer but next time i go in again i have the same problem

Comment: No, I was meaning to clear the site's cache, not your browser's cache. :)

Comment: I never used WP, only Joomla, but try [this](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/recommended-wordpress-plugins/clearing-cache-in-wordpress)